# Angularjs: conditional $on pattern?

Tags: angularjs

I have to use this service

```
angular.service('KitchenService', function(){
    this.lunch = {
       status : null,
        ...
    };

    this.lunchIsReady = function(){
        if(typeof this.lunch.status === "undefined")
          return null;
        else            
          return this.lunch.status;
    }

    this.lunchEvaluated = function(lunchStatus){
         this.lunch.status = lunchStatus;
         $scope.$root.$emit('KitchenServiceEvent:lunch-status-evaluated');
    }
});
```

At a certain time, some component could call this.lunchEvaluated because it has just evaluated the lunch status.

so I develop my controllers as this:

```
...
if(KitchenService.lunchIsReady() == null)
    $scope.$root.$on('KitchenServiceEvent:lunch-status-evaluated', function(){
        if(KitchenService.lunchIsReady())
             takeASeatAtTheTable();
    });
else
   if(KitchenService.lunchIsReady())
        takeASeatAtTheTable();
...
```

Controllers need to enable a listener on that event only if lunch status is not evaluable yet.

Is there a more convenient way to do not replicate this template in all controllers that need to take a place at the table only if lunch is ready or if it will be ready?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive for this which you can apply to each page:

**JS**

```
angular.module('app').directive('lunch', lunchReady);

function lunchReady() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      isReady: '&'
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: ['$scope', 'kitchenService', function($scope, kitchenService) {
      if (kitchenService.lunchIsReady() == null) {
        var deregister = $scope.$root.$on('KitchenServiceEvent:lunch-status-evaluated', function() {
          if (KitchenService.lunchIsReady())
            $scope.isReady();
        });
      } else {
        $scope.isReady();
      }

      $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
         deregister && deregister();
      });
    }]
  }
}
```

**Sample HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <lunch is-ready="vm.lunchReady()">
    other code
  </lunch>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I'd prefer an only programmatically solution keeping unchanged the view. Anyway, your solution could be a first step of    refactoring enhancement.